# PHP if/else switch not working

Tags: php, if-statement

Goal:
Trying to get a rollover button state to remain "ON" when URL equals "enhanced.php".

Problem:
Button state does not remain "on" when URL equals "enhanced.php".

(Button acts correctly as a rollover)

---

sidemenu.php sidemenu.php is used as a PHP include on all pages (I don't know if that makes a difference

```
<?php

$script = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];


//Set the default state to OFF and only turn ON if we are on the current URL.

$enhancedstate = OFF;


$pos = strpos($script, "enhanced.php");
if($pos === true) {
$enhancedstate = ON;
}


?>


 <div class="sideMenu">   

   <a href="enhanced.php" 
      onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','/images/Button_ON_01.gif',1)">
      <img src="/images/Button_<? echo $enhancedstate; ?>_01.gif" name="Image1" border="0">
   </a>
```

---

Anyone see any reason why the button state does not stay "ON" when the current URL is "enhanced.php".
TIA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns a int on success, and FALSE on failure.

Change `if($pos === true)` to `if($pos !== false)`.

The `===` operator compares values and types.  So, on success `strpos` returns an int, which may have the same value as TRUE, but it's not the same type.

EDIT: As others have said, you should change:

`$enhancedstate = OFF` to `$enhancedstate = 'OFF'`

PHP is very forgiving, and will let you use un-quoted strings, but you should try not to, unless ON and OFF are actually constants.

Comment: I blame my flaky connection, +1

Comment: Best site ever. TY from a noob.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) never returns `bool(true)` as a value. It's either `bool(false)` or an `int`.

So, by doing the following:

```
if($pos === true)
```

You are basically looking for a `bool(true)` value which will never happen (`===` checks for type and value).

Change it to:

```
if($pos !== false)
```

Do not use `$pos == true` as this will fail if the string starts with `enhanced.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your strings. Without them, "ON" is treated as a constant.

```
$enhancedstate = 'ON';
```

Comment: They could be constants defined using `define` (e.g. `define("ON", "ON")`, in which case it would be fine to refer to `ON` instead of `"ON"`.

Answer (score 0):

$enhancedstate = stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'enhanced.php') !== false ? 'ON' : 'OFF';

ive never used script_name, but try this one and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if ($pos !== false) {
```

as the test instead. See example #2 (Using !==) in the [manual page for `strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).